# How to dispatch an action from reducer react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I use an event listener in one of my reducers and I need to trigger an action according to the incoming 'type'. I can listen the events i can see the payloads but i cant dispatch another action. The only thing i need to do is dispatch an action. How can I do that ? I cant dispatch from reducer. Im using redux-thunk. I tried to use it with middleware but i cant success. Thank you.

```
import { ADD_NOTIF, REMOVE_NOTIF, CLOSE_NOTIFS } from './actions';
import Notifications from "../util/Notifications";
import { addNotif } from "./actions"
const localStatus = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notifStatus"));
const initialState = { notif: [], notifStatus: localStatus !== null ? localStatus : true }

const NotifReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NOTIF:
      return {
        ...state,
        notif: action.payload,
      };
    case REMOVE_NOTIF:
      return {
        ...state,
        notif: state.notif.filter(i => i.id !== action.payload.id)
      };
    case CLOSE_NOTIFS:
      localStorage.setItem("notifStatus", JSON.stringify(action.payload.status));
      return {
        ...state,
        notifStatus: action.payload.status,
      };
    case 'TWITTER_NET_TWEET':
      return {
        ...state,
        notifStatus: action.payload.tweet
      }
    case 'PHOTO_SAVE_ERROR':
      // Here i have to dispatch addNotif
      return {
        ...state,
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The file i combine the reducers;

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import appReducer from 'containers/Main/reducer';
import notifReducer from '../src/redux/notifreducer';
import GalleryReducer from '../src/redux/Gallery/gallery-reducer';
import PlaneModeReducer from '../src/redux/planeModereducer';
import ContactsReducer from '../src/redux/Contacts/contactsReducer';
import CallReducer from '../src/redux/CallModule/callReducer';
import BackgroundReducer from '../src/redux/Background/background-reducer';
import SoundsReducer from '../src/redux/Sounds/soundsReducer';
import TwitterReducer from '../src/redux/Twitter/twitter-reducer';
import SahibindenReducer from '../src/redux/Sahibinden/sahibinden-reducer';
import BadgeReducer from '../src/redux/BadgeNotifications/badgeReducer';
import NewsReducer from "../src/redux/News/newsReducer";
import NotesReducer from "../src/redux/Notes/notesReducer";
import MessagesReducer from "../src/redux/Messages/messagesReducer";

  const reducers = combineReducers({
    app: appReducer,
    notif: notifReducer,
    gallery: GalleryReducer,
    planeMode: PlaneModeReducer,
    contacts: ContactsReducer,
    inCall: CallReducer,
    background: BackgroundReducer,
    sounds: SoundsReducer,
    twitter: TwitterReducer,
    sahibinden: SahibindenReducer,
    openedApp: BadgeReducer,
    news: NewsReducer,
    messages: MessagesReducer,
    notes: NotesReducer
  });

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using redux-thunk, then you don't need to dispatch the action in the reducer.
You would dispatch the action in an action creator.

If the action that dispatches `PHOTO_SAVE_ERROR` is

```
function add_photo_error()
{
return {type:"PHOTO_SAVE_ERROR"}
}
```

Then you need to rather dispatch another action via thunk that will dispatch both actions.

```
function add_photo_error_and_notification()
{
return (dispatch)=>{
    //dispatch the original action
    dispatch(add_photo_error());

    //dispatch your notification action
    dispatch(addNotif());

}
}
```

edit:

If you simply want to mutate the state in the reducer based on the PHOTO_SAVE_ERROR, you would do something like this

```
const NotifReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NOTIF:
      return {
        ...state,
        notif: action.payload,
      };
    case REMOVE_NOTIF:
      return {
        ...state,
        notif: state.notif.filter(i => i.id !== action.payload.id)
      };
    case CLOSE_NOTIFS:
      localStorage.setItem("notifStatus", JSON.stringify(action.payload.status));
      return {
        ...state,
        notifStatus: action.payload.status,
      };
    case 'TWITTER_NET_TWEET':
      return {
        ...state,
        notifStatus: action.payload.tweet
      }
    case 'PHOTO_SAVE_ERROR':
      // Notice that this is the same mutation as the ADD_NOTIF action
     return {
        ...state,
        notif: "PHOTO SAVE ERROR",// replace this with whatever is available in the action object. 
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: My event listener sends me 'PHOTO_SAVE_ERROR'. I have to dispatch addNotif after this event. I cant understand where should i use these functions ?

Comment: Dispatching addNotif has the effect of triggering the ADD_NOTIF in the switch/case in your notification reducer, which will mutate the redux state. 

Therefore you don't need to dispatch the any additional action, you can simply return your desired updated state.

I have edited the original post for clarification.